# How did i lose here when we both had flush J High?

Tags: nlhe

Am i wrong in thinking that we both had Flush J High here https://gyazo.com/8d813f78aa0ddca4a6be4bd5f08f8d51

Comment: Best FIVE cards every time.  I hope that is not real money.

Comment: So the question in the description raises another point. You were CORRECT in your thinking, you both have Jack High Flushes here, but 'Sn00ks' has the BETTER Jack High Flush given his best 5-card hand beats your best 5-card hand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poker hands have FIVE cards. Exactly five, no more, no fewer. Even in flushes and no-pair hands, all five count toward value. J-8-7-5-4 beats J-8-6-5-4.

Comment: Why do you say that in no-pair hands all five cards count toward value? It implies that in paired hands there is an exception. Or perhaps the emphasis that you're trying to portray is that "EVEN in flushes and no-pair hands, all five count toward value."?

Comment: Perhaps that could be worded better; I was responding to the particular hand in the question.

Comment: Ah, I understand now! I got confused myself so I have proposed an edit that specifies the meaning so that this isn't interpreted as EXCLUSIVELY in flushes and no-pair hands